# Dynamic list in html email template

Tags: html, html-email

I am creating an email template with simple HTML. But I am stuck where I have to list down the list which data comes from java code. Also, I am not sure the length of the list which is getting each time.

I have tried to do something like the below code. But it did not work.

```html
<span style="font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;font-family: Calibri;">Dear $customer,</b></span><br>
<br>
<br>
<span style="font-size:14px;font-family: Calibri;">Below List of Products orderd</br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><ul>
        <li>$ProdID</li>
      </ul></th>
    <th><ul>
        <li>$PrdoName</li>
      </ul></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
Thank you for choosing US </br>
</br>
Genuinely,<br />
<br />
<span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;font-family: Calibri;">E - commerce</span></span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><hr noshade size=1 width="100%" style="margin:0" align=left>
    <div id="footerTxt" style=" font-family: Calibri;line-height:18px; margin:20px 0;">
    <span style="font-size:12px; color:#999"><br />
    &copy;E-Commerce L.P. </span>
```

Please help me to print $prodID as a list, I have passed the value as a list of string

Comment: You are using `ul` & `li`. Have you tried tables? It will be easy and will look better. You look can fill in table columns and rows if there is data.

Comment: Are you using java or php? because as much as i understand $ProdID and $PrdoName represent PHP variables

Comment: Morevover, the html is also incorrect. because u have already closed the table before "Thank you for choosing US" and then below we can see the reference of closing <td>

Comment: @SandhyaNair I am using java

Answer (score 0):

I assume the langyage used for html templating is PHP as the variables are preceded by $ symbol. Please refer by code below

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
      <td><span style="font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;font-family: Calibri;">Dear <?php echo $customer?>,</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><span style="font-size:14px;font-family: Calibri;">Below List of Products ordered:</span></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
               <tr>
                   <th>Prod ID</th>
                   <th>Prod Name</th>
               </tr>
               <?php foreach($products as $product) {?>
               <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $product->prodID ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $product->prodName ?></td>
               </tr>
               <?php } ?>
           </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Thank you for choosing US </br>
            Genuinely,<br /><br />
            <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;font-family: Calibri;">E - commerce</span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr noshade size=1 width="100%" style="margin:0" align=left>
            <div id="footerTxt" style=" font-family: Calibri;line-height:18px; margin:20px 0;"><span style="font-size:12px; color:#999"><br />&copy;E-Commerce L.P. </span></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```